# Get hashmap using reflection Java, code error

Tags: java, reflection

I am attempting to load the corresponding hashmap using reflection. However I get a field not found exception. Please let me know what you think the issue is. Thanks

```
//Find the map
        HashMap<String, Matches> map = null;

        //Reflection to find the appropriate map
        try {
            Field field = Field.class.getField(mapName); //exception (mapname = lookupHashmap) this class has a lookupHashmap declared)
            try {

                //Set the map
                map = (HashMap<String, Matches>)field.get(this); //Not sure if this is correct

            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Stack trace

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: majorFieldLookup
    at java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:1522)
    at MatchingGraph.getResultsForMap(MatchingGraph.java:245)
    at MatchingGraph.getmajorFieldMatches(MatchingGraph.java:196)
    at Matcher.findMatches(Matcher.java:95)
    at Tester.main(Tester.java:27)
```

Comment: What does `mapName` contain? You are trying to get a field called whatever `mapName` is from the class `Field` with this method call `Field.class.getField(mapName);`. That is almost definitely not what you want.

Comment: is your map private? if it is you need to use `getDeclaredField` instead, and you need to use `setAccessible = true` in order to be able to manipulate it.

Comment: Map is public. This class (called Matcher) has a hashmap declared called lookupMap.

Comment: @waf See rolfl's answer. You need the class object of your class not `Field.class`

Comment: The stack trace just just shows NoSuchFieldException (and it is called at  Field field = Field.class.getField(mapName);

Comment: Changed to MatchingGraph.class.getField(mapName) and still error

Comment: @waf See Rodrigo's comment.

Comment: getDeclaredField worked (it was a private map). Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not want `Field.class.getField(mapName);`

You want to use whatever class it is you have the map on, call it 'MyClass'

```
Field field = MyClass.class.getDeclaredField(mapName);
```

Edit: changed to getDeclaredField(...) from getField(..) because the field was private.

Comment: Might want to add details about not being able to get it if it is private.

Comment: Tried, doesn't work. Changed to MatchingGraph.class.getField(mapName) and still error

Comment: @rolfl The field is probably private. Needs `getDeclaredField()`

Answer (score 0):

@Rolfl solved your problem i guess.

And  I'm suggesting [Apache Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/).

And use the method

```
BeanUtils.copyProperties(source, target);
```

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/